# Connect two third party modules with "const char*" and "char*" arguments

Tags: c++

I have two third party modules and I have to combine them. 
First I get data from a class. I will submit this data to a function.

```
bool loadLibrary(const char *strPlugName){
  HPLUGIN temp = _BASS_PluginLoad(strPlugName,0);
  return false;
}
```

The `const char * strPlugName` is a value that I got from another library. I cannot change this value type myself.

Inside the function I try to call a BASS Library function.

```
HPLUGIN temp = _BASS_PluginLoad(strPlugName,0);
Definition: typedef HPLUGIN (*BASS_PluginLoad_Type)(char *file,DWORD flags);
```

Here Xcode tell me:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'const char *'
```

My question is how I can convert or cast this `const char *` to `char *`?

Comment: Not to get crucified, but [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) ... ouch...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If and only if** the function called via `_BASS_PluginLoad` doesn't alter the memory pointed at by `file`, you can use a `const_cast`:

```
HPLUGIN temp = _BASS_PluginLoad(const_cast<char*>(strPlugName),0);
```

Some old [c](/questions/tagged/c) API's are not const correct on account of the `const` keyword being a fairly late addition to the C language. But they still don't mutate their arguments, so a `const_cast` is the easiest way to make use of them in const correct C++ wrappers. It's a perfectly legitimate reason (maybe even *the* reason) for that cast.

Comment: Note that only *some* APIs can be fixed like this.  Others actually *do* temporarily mutate their argument.  (There's a notorious Win32 API which does this, but I can't remember which it is.)

Answer (score 6):

The easy and safe way is to copy the argument into a local buffer, and then pass a pointer to that.  As you are using C++, you can automate the memory management.

```
bool loadLibrary(const char *strPlugName){
  std::string local(strPlugName);
  local.push_back('\0'); // Ensure null terminated, if not using C++11 or greater
  HPLUGIN temp = _BASS_PluginLoad(&local[0],0);
  return false;
}
```

If using C++17, you can just call `local.data()` instead of `&local[0]`.

Language lawyer caveat:

Strictly speaking, `&local[0]` was not defined to work in C++98 - in practice it always did (and later versions of the standard defined it to work).

Comment: You can skip the null termination since C++11 if memory serves. You do need C++17 for the const correct `local.data()` however.

Comment: @StoryTeller `local.data()` is null-terminated in C++11, but I'm not sure `&local[0]` is - BICBW.

Comment: They both produce the same buffer (as does `c_str`) since C++11. The null terminator is guaranteed.